# is there an easy or right way to remove spring security plugin?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, spring-security

I am using intellij for grails development.

I would like to know whether there is an easier way to remove the spring security core plugin dependency from the project.

The project is matured so there are spring security references in lot of places. The way i have in mind is to first remove the plugin from build config and then one by one check all files and remove any references to spring security. This is time consuming.

So i am wondering if there are efficient ways to achieve this. Are there intellij features that help with this? I doubt there is a tool to automatically remove all references to spring security.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you no longer need to know who is logged in?  If so, then follow the instructions below.  If you still need that info, but will use a different method, then I suggest wrapping all usages of springSecurityService in your own code (we call it userInfoService).  That way you can change over to a different security implementation at your leisure, without affecting the application code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way to remove this dependency and its usage from all the classes. However, Intellij can make life little easier. Few things you can try:

1) Go to project Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Compiler: select `Build project automatically` and `Compile independent modules in parallel`. This will highlight classes that got affected by removal of Spring Security dependency.

2) Remove Spring Security from build configuration.

3) Find or Replace, `ctrl`+`shift`+`R` or `ctrl`+`shift`+`F`, then on top right corner of the window, select `Regex` and use `.*org.spring.*.security.*`. This will find all the text that has Spring Security reference. Either remove it one by one or replace all with blank line.

4) Manually go to classes that are highlighted because of error, manually remove code that has reference of Spring Security.